# Song with same backing track as Daft Punk's "Something About Us"

Tags: identify-this-song, electronic-music

This song seems to have the same backing track as Daft Punk's "Something About Us," but it has a different singer, and different lyrics that sound like "It must be here, the day begins, 7:13."

I know the sampled music is from Daft Punk but I am searching for is this version and NOT Daft Punk's "Something About Us." I heard this version in various places. Shazam is no help.

Here is the audio sample of the music I am searching for. https://youtu.be/4luUnd-brQ8

Here is a video with a bit more audio WORNING might be considered as NSFW
https://youtu.be/KxClLH1LA2M

Comment: np i got a longer audio sample but it's still no god unless a person knows what song it is. Google doesn't find lyrics nor audio recognition software .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I, unfortunately cannot find any background on this track, but I have found multiple copies of the full track itself.

Here is the oldest copy I have been able to find, not necessarily the original source, but I have been unable to locate a version that was uploaded earlier than this one:

```
(July 18, 2011)
```

https://soundcloud.com/heartbreakergrl94/erekle-s-ani

A couple days later, the same user re-uploaded the same track with an English title.

```
(July 21, 2011)
```

https://soundcloud.com/heartbreakergrl94/its-comin-back-at-you

Hopefully this is able to satisfy your question.

Answer (score -1):

search "brodymccain soundcloud"

2 songs has same backing track but two completely set of lyrics and melodies. You can't even tell they're the same backing track unless you were listening for it. The lyrics of each song takes the listener to two entirely different places.

Check out drivin and dreamin 
&
Hello Heartache

Comment: pls give links to the 2 songs